# if I click icon ,hide images and show another images using fadeIn() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two icon, left icon and right icon. If I clicked right icon, I want to hide first icon's images, and then I want to show right icon's images using `fadeIn()` function. But, it isn't successful completely. If I used `fadeIn()` function, it didn't work. I have two `<div>` with differnt id and one is display:none.

**here is my code:**

```
<div class="item_set " id="images1" >
<div class="item_set " id="images2" style="display:none;">
    <div id="dot_block"><!--start dots-->
        <div id="dot1" class="dots current" ></div>
        <div id="dot2" class="dots" "></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#dot2').click(function(){
         $('#images').hide().fadeIn(2000);
        $('#images2').show().fadeOut(3000);
        $('#dot2').css({'background':'#D0C083'});
        $('#dot1').css({'background':'#DBDBEA'});        
        $('#dot2').removeAttr('onclick');       
     });

    $('#dot1').click(function(){
        $('#images2').hide().fadeIn(2000);
        $('#image1').show().fadeOut(3000);
        $('#dot1').css({'background':'#D0C083'});
        $('#dot2').css({'background':'#DBDBEA'});              
        $('#dot1').removeAttr('onclick');       
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: *"I have two <div> with same id"* - Using the same ID for two elements is invalid in HTML, except in practice the HTML you've shown doesn't do that. Where is the HTML for the `#image1` and `#images2` elements?

Comment: try without `hide()` and `show()`